# Prototype serialize function is not recognized

Tags: javascript, forms, prototypejs

I am working on using prototype to submit a simple login form:

http://huddlee.homeip.net/danny/

For some reason, whenever I try using the serialize function of the form it says it cannot find the function even though the prototype library is clearly being loaded.

So this function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert($('login').serialize());
</script>
```

gives me this error:

$("login").serialize is not a function.

Any ideas? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the body tag with id = "login", that's the problem.

Remember id's must be unique...

Try to [validate](http://validator.w3.org/) your pages...

Line 25, Column 14: ID "login" already defined

```
<form id="login" action="#" onsubmit="login(); return false;">
```